# Modification of a read-only value attempted when i am trying parsing

Tags: regex, perl

I am getting error : Modification of a read-only value attempted

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$s = '10/25/95';

print "\$s = $s";

($1, $2, $3) = ($s =~ /(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})/); # getting error here

print "$1 $2 $3 \n";

print 'Done..."
```

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` should be something you always use. Not using them does not avoid trouble, it only hides it.

Answer (score 6):

You can't assign to `$1`, `$2`, etc. variables as these are read-only.

What you want is

```
my $s = '10/25/95';
print "\$s = $s";

print "$1 $2 $3 \n" if $s =~ /(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})/;
```

or

```
if (my ($x, $y, $z) = $s =~ /(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})/ ) {

  print "$x $y $z \n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a misunderstanding concerning how `$1`, `$2`, etc are initialized.

Observe this documentation [perlretut - Extracting Matches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches):

> #### Extracting matches
>
> The grouping metacharacters `()` also serve another completely different function: they allow the extraction of the parts of a string that matched. This is very useful to find out what matched and for text processing in general. For each grouping, the part that matched inside goes into the special variables `$1`, `$2`, etc. They can be used just as ordinary variables:
>
> ```
>        # extract hours, minutes, seconds
>        if ($time =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/) {    # match hh:mm:ss format
>            $hours = $1;
>            $minutes = $2;
>            $seconds = $3;
>        }
> ```
>
> [read more...](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches)

As you can see, the regex engine automatically initializes the capture group variables if a pattern matches.  The one thing that is important is to use an `if` to verify that your regex actually matches before attempting to use the captured variables.

Also, be sure to include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.  This is the #1 thing that you can do to be a better Perl programmer.

The following is how I would rework your script following these fixes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = '10/25/95';

print "\$s = $s\n";

if ($s =~ m{(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{2,4})}) {
    print "$1 $2 $3 \n";
} else {
    warn "Unable to match pattern";
}

print 'Done...';
```

Outputs:

```
$s = 10/25/95
10 25 95 
Done...
```